# What is this fighter jet seen at Centennial Airport?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

This is my first post here! yay! Today I ate at the awesome "Perfect Landing" restaurant at [Centennial Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centennial_Airport). My dad said he thought they were FA-18s but I honestly have no idea. It was awesome because we saw the pilots through the window of the flight crew lounge in their military suits. We also saw them go out with some little kids and their families to show them the jets while they were being inspected before takeoff. Really cool to see.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

That is a Boeing F/A-18E Super Hornet.  The Super Hornet can be readily identified from legacy F-18s by its larger size, enlarged, hood-like leading edge extensions, larger flaps and flight control surfaces, and the rhombohedral shaped engine intakes to reduce the aircraft’s frontal radar cross section.  It’s tail insignia indicates that it’s a line aircraft with the United States Navy’s VFA-143 “Pukin’ Dogs” strike fighter squadron based out of NAS Oceania, near Norfolk, VA.

Comment: `+1` for the squadron. I can see an 'AG', also [on those](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:VF-143_F-14_F-18_2005.jpg), any idea what it stands for?

Comment: It’s a unit specific tail code.  All VFA-143 aircraft wear the AG code on the tail.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Navy_and_U.S._Marine_Corps_Aircraft_Tail_Codes

Comment: Wow I can’t believe how much information you can tell me from 1 picture! That’s really cool and now I know some awesome information about the squadron itself. There were 3 of these jets here.

Comment: Wow - “***rhombohedral shaped***”- after I look that up, I am definitely going to have to find a way to use that phrase in a conversation this week!  +1

Comment: That's a very complete answer. Well done.

Comment: @Sorsor_7 not sure if this is still the case, but also used to be A codes were for wings on the Atlantic coast and N codes for the Pacific coast (both Navy wings, USMC uses different conventions).

Comment: "It’s a unit specific tail code. All VFA-143 aircraft wear the AG code on the tail."  Technically true at the time the photo was taken, but potentially misleading.  The "unit" in this case is the carrier airwing, not the squadron.  If the squadron were to be reassigned, as often happens, it would sport new tail letters to match all the other squadrons in the wing.